# How to fix "Calls: library Execution halted" error while knitting in r?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am just trying to knit default Rmarkdonw code (about mtcars) into HTML (or even PDF) and it is not working. Following is the complete error message in the Rmarkdown console:

```
Error in !character.only : invalid argument type
Calls: library
Execution halted
```

Following is the default code in knit:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Piyush Verma"
date: "December 19, 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both contents as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

I have also tried doing following things but nothing worked:

1. `Tools`-->`Global options`-->`Sweave`-->`Weave RNW files using`...from `sweave` to `knitr`
2. Reinstalling both rmarkdown and knitr and attaching the libraries before running the knit option

Any suggestions much appreciated. This is in regard to submission of final projcet for John Hopkin's Practical Machine Learning Course.

Comment: your code runs for me without error

Comment: @Hardikgupta Can you kindly let me know your settings, please?

Comment: No settings at all. Just created a new markdown file and ran the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello everyone who tried to help.

I was able to fix the problem by reinstalling both R and RStudio. 
After reinstalling and running the default Rmarkdown code, RStudio wanted to install Rmarkdown package again and it worked at the end.

Thank you.